# i get the percentage symbols when i use the xliff

Tags: java, android

Ok im trying to translate the app for my udacity class so I copied the code snippet in to my app but when i run the app i get the % symbol in the order summary. Please help me.`

```
  Name for the order summary. It will be shown in the format of "Name: Amy" where Amy is the
  user's name. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE]
-->
<string name="order_summary_name">Name: <xliff:g id="name" example="Amy">%s</xliff:g></string>

<!--
  Whipped cream topping for the order summary. It will be shown in the format of
  "Add whipped cream? true" or "Add whipped cream? false". [CHAR LIMIT=NONE]
-->
<string name="order_summary_whipped_cream">Add whipped cream? <xliff:g id="addWhippedCream" example="true">%b</xliff:g></string>

<!--
  Chocolate topping for the order summary. It will be shown in the format of
  "Add chocolate? true" or "Add chocolate? false". [CHAR LIMIT=NONE]
-->
<string name="order_summary_chocolate">Add chocolate? <xliff:g id="addChocolate" example="true">%b</xliff:g></string>

<!--
  Quantity of coffee cups for the order summary. It will be shown in the format of
  "Quantity: 2", where 2 is the number of cups ordered. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE]
-->
<string name="order_summary_quantity">Quantity: <xliff:g id="quantity" example="2">%d</xliff:g></string>

<!--
  Total price for the order summary. It will be shown in the format of
  "Total: $10" where $10 is the price. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE]
-->
<string name="order_summary_price">Total: <xliff:g id="price" example="$10">%s</xliff:g></string>

<!-- Thank you message for the order summary. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="thank_you">Thank you!</string>

<!--
  Subject line for the order summary email. It will be in the format of
  "Just Java order for Amy" where Amy is the user's name. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE]
-->
<string name="order_summary_email_subject">Just java for: <xliff:g id="name" example="Amy">%s</xliff:g></string>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I think you omitted format arguments when calling [`getString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)). See if you have something like `getString(R.string.order_summary_name)`, add a `name` string to the end of the argument list should fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.